# multi-language support with smarty template

Tags: php, smarty, multilingual

What is the best way for supporting a multi-language site in smarty template?

I have read http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=SmartyMultilanguageSupport
and http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/fr/language.config.variables.tpl and now I can't make a decision which option I will to use.

Are there other options?

Answer (score 0):

I use a $_get['lang'] to get the language to be used. In the template, for every pages I get 2 ifs, one if EN another if FR and I generate the code accordingly.

The header footer and meta data comes from database and based on the language, the row required by the language will be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

I read language from cookies and set/change it with http request. Based on the languge used, I just change field names (in php) to query from database (including all strings on page - they are stored for each language in different fields - I know that this is not very scalable, but will be enough for this kind of sites). Additionally I set one smarty variable to language code and when needed (rarely, because strings are already localised), I use smarty {if $language ...} structures to change output.

Answer (score 0):

Someone might find this interesting. Basically lang variable to get the current language and loads a file via config_load. Both are basically the same, just that your first link has all the functions needed packed into a small module.

http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/creating_multilingual_website_smarty